# How to apply VBA code to all worksheets in the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

This code should delete rows that contain specific text and apply it to all the sheets in the workbook.

When I try this code, it applies to only one worksheet.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

     Dim c As Integer
     Dim n As Integer
     c = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
     For n = 1 To c Step 1
        Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For I = Last To 1 Step -1
            If (Cells(I, "A").Value) = "Text" Then
                Cells(I, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next I
     Next n

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code below, use `With ws` statement to test all rows in that relevant sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub WorksheetLoop()

Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long

' loop through all worksheets
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        Last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = Last To 1 Step -1
            If (.Cells(i, "A").Value) = "Text" Then
                .Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not working because you never qualify the worksheet that you want to work with in your code. The simple fix, keeping your code mainly as is is below.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

 Dim c As Integer
 Dim n As Integer
 c = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
 For n = 1 To c Step 1
    Last = Worksheets(n).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Worksheets(n).Cells(I, "A").Value) = "Text" Then
            Worksheets(n).Cells(I, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next I
 Next n

 End Sub
```

The above works by using the Worksheet Index property with the `n` variable you have created.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this. It's almost exactly like Shai's answer, but I activate each worksheet.   (The next worksheet doesn't automatically activate in the 'For each'; you have to manually activate it each step )

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Walk through each worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Activate

'Add your code here

Next ws
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify sheet in your range operations, otherwise it works with ActiveSheet in each iteration.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

 Dim c As Integer
 Dim n As Integer
 c = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
 For n = 1 To c Step 1
    Last = Sheets(n).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = Last To 1 Step -1
        If (Sheets(n).Cells(I, "A").Value) = "Text" Then
            Sheets(n).Cells(I, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next I
 Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: using `Sheets` will fail if there is a chart sheet in the workbook. Probably isn't based on the OP, but worth noting, I think.